# Run specs on axslx generated files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, axlsx

My goal here is to run specs on files generated by [axlsx-rails](http://blog.timothyandrew.net/blog/2013/05/01/writing-custom-rspec-matchers/) gem, and use a custom rspec matcher I found [here](http://blog.timothyandrew.net/blog/2013/05/01/writing-custom-rspec-matchers/).

In my spec example, I have:

```
describe Statistic::CompanyTableSetsController do
  login_user # this just for Devise Auth
  it "generates a proper excel sheet" do
    ...
    get "show", format: :xlsx, id: id
    response.content_type.to_s.should eq Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(:xlsx).to_s
  end
end
```

But when I run my test, I get :

```
Failure/Error: response.content_type.to_s.should eq Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(:xlsx).to_s

   expected: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        got: "text/html"
```

And of course I can't get the worksheet in other spec examples...

Think I miss something here, because in my browser, the Excel sheet is generated normally.

Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your test log if your request is coming through with the xlsx format. Your test should be working fine.

Is `get` appending the `format` as a query string parameter? Perhaps you need:

```
get "/company_table_sets/#{id}.xlsx"
```

You should also be able to use:

```
response.content_type.to_s.should eq Mime::XLSX.to_s
```